# No-SQL Server Services Displaying. Resolution : DB Engine must be installed

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am unable to register new server & also not displaying existing servers. even SQL server configuration manager not listed the services, and through command services also not listed. i installed Microsoft SQL Server management studio 2014. i recently reset my system settings. i am using windows 10.

Comment: Is the sql server browser service running on the machine where sql server is installed ?

Comment: No, its not there. I checked in <services.msc> There only sql server VSS writer available. its running. In command promt says service name invalid <net start sqlbrowser>

Comment: after installing sql server you should have a minimum of 3 services. Sql Server itself, sql server agent and sql server browser. The first and the last must be running. If you are missing the browser service than you are not checking on the machine where sql server was installed or there went something seriously wrong

Comment: I never noticed and seen before. I will try to fix manually or else i will uninstall and will do new set up. I hope this works.

Comment: DB engine not installed, only client tools(work station) installed so that its not showing the SQL Server name. It seems we wont find all the required files in one set up file in Microsoft website. May be need more files than Microsfot SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Its only for client tools that i could found.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio is not the database, it is only the tool to configure your database. Yes you need another installer and yes the microsoft download site is not at all easy to understand these days